# How to visible a li ul only for a one page and in other pages li ul should not be visible

Tags: jquery, css

In my website all the ul tags inside li tag are set as display none. But in one page I want to visible this ul tags inside li tag. How can I do this.

Comment: Add an additional css to that page only that will override the style that hides `ul` elements.

Comment: Or add the style directly inline to the element.

Comment: I used display:block to the ul tag inside li tag. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
 <body class="my-special-page">
```

css

```
.my-special-page ul li { display:block;}
```